# GetResponse html code in landing page opt in form?

Tags: html

I got myself a custom landing page with a name and email opt in form, I can't figure out where to put the getresponse webform code in the landing page html.

here is the landing page html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    background-color: #BA0A0A;
}
.style14 {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold; color: #FFFFFF; }
.style15 {color: #FFFFFF}
.style3 {font-family: Tahoma;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.style4 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000000;
}
.style10 {
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #0033CC;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.style21 {font-family: Tahoma; color: #B30006; }
-->
</style>
<link href="whitelinks.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style24 {
    color: #FFCC33;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.style26 {color: #05320B}
.style27 {color: #0033CC}
a:link {
    color: #0033CC;
}
a:visited {
    color: #0033CC;
}
a:hover {
    color: #0033CC;
}
a:active {
    color: #0033CC;
}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table width="768" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" background="images/768header.jpg">
  <tr>
    <td height="150"><table width="768" height="150" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="30" height="100">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="400"><div align="center" class="style3">
          <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
        </div></td>
        <td width="338">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td height="50">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="768" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" background="images/fillertable.jpg">
  <tr>
    <td><div align="right">
      <blockquote>
        <blockquote>
          <p></p>
        </blockquote>
      </blockquote>
    </div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="768" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td height="300" background="images/middle.jpg"><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="768">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td background="images/middle.jpg" height="300"><table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="768">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td background="images/main.jpg" height="300"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="290" width="768">
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td rowspan="3" width="30">&nbsp;</td>
                          <td height="60" width="200">&nbsp;</td>
                          <td rowspan="3" width="50">&nbsp;</td>
                          <td rowspan="3" valign="top" width="428"><div align="center">
                              <h1 class="style21">FIRE YOUR BOSS! </h1>
                              <p align="right" class="style4">Download your FREE 10 Page report on getting<br> 
                                started on your own BusinessToday! </p>
                              <div align="left">
                                <p class="style26"></p>
                                </div>
                          </div></td>
                          <td rowspan="3" width="50">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td><center>
                              <form method="post" action="https://app.getresponse.com/site/johnmilner28/webform.html?wid=9908905&u=1vzV&mg_param3=4">
                                <input name="meta_web_form_id" value="yournumericvaluehere" type="hidden">
                                <input name="meta_split_id" value="" type="hidden">
                                <input name="unit" value="yournlistnamehere" type="hidden">
                                <input name="redirect" value="http://www.yourredirectpage.com/more.html" type="hidden">
                                <input name="meta_adtracking" value="sqtp001" type="hidden">
                                <input name="meta_message" value="1" type="hidden">
                                <input name="meta_required" value="from" type="hidden">
                                <input name="meta_forward_vars" value="0" type="hidden">
                                <table>
                                  <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td colspan="2"><center>
                                          <div>&nbsp;</div>
                                      </center></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td class="style14">Email:*</td>
                                      <td><input name="from" value="" size="20" type="text"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td><span class="style14">Name</span><span class="style15">:*</span></td>
                                      <td><input name="name" value="" size="20" type="text"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                      <td colspan="2" align="center"><input name="submit" value="Show me!!" type="submit"></td>
                                    </tr>
                                  </tbody>
                                </table>
                              </form>
                          </center></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td height="50">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                  </table></td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
          </table></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width="768" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="style27"><img src="images/base.jpg" width="768" height="140"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div align="center"><span class="style10"><a href="yourlinkghere" target="_blank">Terms &amp; Conditions</a> | <a href="yourlinkhere" target="_blank">Income Disclaimer</a> | <a href="yoursupportdesk">SupportDesk</a></span><span class="style27"><font face="MS Sans Serif"><br>
  </font><span class="style24">Copyright 2007 &copy; YOUR COPY INFORMATION HERE </span></span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the getresponse code: http://pastebin.com/hkusHw1y

Anyone know anything about this kind of stuff? I've been trying to figure it out all day.

Comment: Did the answer I provided help you? If so, please accept it or comment on it to help others as well.

Answer (score 0):

The code you linked to actually seems to contain two different parts. Everything between `<style>` and `<\style>` should go inside the `<head>` section of your page. The rest of it lives in the `<body>` part of your page.

Moreover it is usually good practice to put the `<script>...</script>` line at the very end of your `<body>` so immediately before `</body>`. That way you are sure the all the DOM elements are loaded.

If you intent to work with this kind of stuff more often, you should start with some tutorials and small scale examples. Also I am confident that the getResponse page would have good instructions where to put their code on their website.